# Filter Iframe by domain name;

Tags: security, iframe, x-frame-options

how can I allow my site to be framed just in : http://myDomain.com; and my site has different url; so

```
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="sameorigin">
```

doesn't work and

```
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="ALLOW-FROM http://myDomain.com">
```

isn't supported by all browsers;
thanks for your help;

Comment: You need to add it in at scripting language or web server level as a header. Which technology stack are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but you're going to have to write some script.

The standard framebreaker script looks like this:

```
if( top != self ) {
    top.location.href = self.location.href; 
}
```

You can tailor this to taste, like this:

```
if (top != self) {
    if (top.location.toLower().indexOf("http://mydomain.com/") != 0) {
        top.location.href = "http://mydomain.com/error.html";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks SilverlightFox & John Wu for your answers;
I tried  this : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Protection_for_Java_EE
to do it in the server side and it worked well;